# Map tips Flashing

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I am using some very basic html in a point shapefile's layer properties to display a photo.

```
<b> [% "filename" %]
<br>
<img src= [% "filepath" %] />
<br>
```

It will display fine, but it flashes.  By flashing I mean when I hover the mouse of the point, the map tip with the image comes up, but within a second or 2 it will disappear.  If I leave the mouse there, it will flash like this none stop.

I have noticed that it is only when trying to insert an image.  With other shape files in which text is displayed it works fine.  Anybody know why it is doing this?  Could the image file be to large? Its a .jpg at 1024x576 resolution.

---

Actually, the issue is occurring if the point is in the center of the window. Its almost like the map tip pop up is "interrupting" itself.

Answer (score 2):

Uuups it's an old question, I guess it's solved since 2 years!?
If not, indeed your 'flashing issue' is probably caused by the size of your image which is extending out of the frame of your canevas. I experienced the same problem.

To solve it, try one of these solutions (the first being the best):

- add a size restriction parameter in the  expression, your can
  specify `width` and/or `height` (in pixels). For example:
  `<img src=[% "filepath" %] width=400> </img>`
- resize your source pictures
- buy a wider screen ;-)